# Put each record in different columns and in different rows with php y sqlserver

Tags: php, tcpdf

When generating a report with TCPDF I would like to place the withdrawals in the debit column and deposits in the credit column, the problem I have is that they appear in the same row, if it is the same date, I would like to place them in different rows so that it does not remain deposits and withdrawals in the same row but in different row[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV10H.png)s, at the moment I have it like this.

my code is the following

```
$ver = $obj->ListarTodasCuentas();
$pdf->Ln(2);
//var_dump($ver);
$saldo_f = 18050;
/*
if ($saldo_f > 0) {
    $pdf->SetX(40);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 0, '---- SALDO ANTERIOR -----', 0, 0, 'L');
    $pdf->SetX(165);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 0, 'Q.'.$saldo_f, 0, 0, 'L');
    $pdf->Ln(5);
}
*/
$saldo_fin = 0;
$cont = 0;

 foreach ($ver as $r):
$cont++;

$salto = 0;

//$salto = $salto + 38;
    $r->tra_fecha;
    $r->ttr_descripcion;
    $r->tra_valor;

    switch ($r->ttr_descripcion) {
    case 'RETIRO':

      $ret = $r->tra_valor;
      $dep = '';
      $retiro = 'Q.'.number_format($ret, 2);

     //$dep = '';
     // $saldo_fin = $ret;

      $saldo_f = ($saldo_f - $ret);
      $saldo_fin = 'Q.'.number_format($saldo_f, 2);
      break;
    case 'DEPOSITOS':
      $dep = $r->tra_valor;
      $ret = '';
      $deposito = 'Q.'.number_format($dep, 2);
      //$ret = '';

      $saldo_f = ($saldo_f + $dep);
      $saldo_fin = 'Q.'.number_format($saldo_f, 2);
      break;
  }

    $pdf->SetX(6);
    $pdf->Cell(16, 0, $r->tra_fecha, 0, 0, 'L');
    $pdf->SetX(32);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 0, $r->ttr_descripcion, 0, 0, 'L');
    $pdf->SetX(100);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 0, $retiro, 0, 0, 'L');
    $pdf->SetX(135);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 0, @$deposito, 0, 0, 'L');
    $pdf->SetX(173);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 0, $saldo_fin, 0, 0, 'L');
    $pdf->Ln(5);

  endforeach;
```

but I do not understand how to place the data and the description in different rows. For the result I would like it to stay like this, any suggestions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHmGB.png)

Comment: let me see this:  var_dump($ver);

Comment: i think you can group elements of $ver by date in a new array.  Then process every date through a function where you can simply menage conditions creating new rows if necessary  filled  with data in correct place.  Return one or more  rows for each date.  Add this returned rows to your table.  At the end, loop the array table and fill your pdf row schema